# Xamarin + iOS симулятор

Tags: windows, ios, xamarin

Подскажите, какой iOS эмулятор можно использовать в связке с VS 2017 Xamarin. Да я понимаю что в Xamarina есть свой этимулятор, но он работает только с VS Enterprise.

Comment: вот такой: http://macincloud.com (если хватит ума сообразить как это работает, то очень полезная вещь, хоть и не бесплатная) или скачайте и поставьте VS enterprise. на торрентах разве нет?

Comment: Есть куча бесплатных, вопрос какой ...

Comment: куча бесплатных симуляторов iOS - это звучит как куча Больших Адронных Коллайдеров

Comment: Колайдер тоже не один. VS enterprise - не возможно использовать!

Comment: Нашёл Air iPhone Emulator. Кстати и Xcode - тоже имеет свой эмулятор.

Comment: И это много? кстати, macincloud.com не эмулятор - это мак в аренду. причем мак физический, не виртуалка. там стоит xcode, а в нем тот самый эмулятор.

Comment: Значит ставим Xcode по Windows, может и кому-то нужно облако, я не против, но меня интересует локальная связка, без закачки исходников на чужие платформы.

Comment: iPadian, MobiOne Studio. Вот кстати Xamarin Testflight - отдельно, но я не нашёл где его скачать.

Answer (score 2):

В любом случаи Вам придется использовать Mac OS.

Все танцы с бубном вокруг "бесплатных", выйдут боком при скорости разработки/отладки и тестировании на реальном устройстве.

Купить/найдите mac компьютер и используйте любую версию VS 2017. Даже Community подойдет, так как потребует установку Xcode который устанавливает данный эмулятор и позволяет его использовать на приличной скорости.